# C++ Winsock struct send/recv

Tags: c++, sockets, struct, winsock2

I am attempting to send a struct via a winsock UDP socket from client to server, but I am not receiving the same bytes that have been sent, or at least not being to reassemble the struct correctly.

```
struct Header
{
  uint16_t sender;
  uint16_t number;
  uint16_t packetSize;
  uint16_t type; 
};
```

Sending struct:

```
Header header;
header.sender = 1;
header.number = 2;
header.packetSize = 3;
header.type = 4;

char buffer[sizeof(Header)];
memcpy(buffer, &header, sizeof(Header));

 int bytesSent = sendto(sendSocket_, data, sizeof(Header), 0, (const sockaddr*)&sendSocketAddr_, sizeof(sendSocketAddr_));
  if (bytesSent > 0)
  {
    cout << bytesSent << endl;
  }
```

Receiving struct:

```
char *data = new char[sizeof(Header)];
  int bytesRecv = recv(listenSocket_, data, sizeof(Header), 0);
  if (bytesRecv > 0)
  {
    cout << bytesRecv << endl;
    Header header;
    memcpy(&header, data, sizeof(data));
    cout << header.sender << ": " << header.number << ": " << header.packetSize << ": " << header.type << endl;
}
```

The same amount of bytes are received as are sent, however once copied back into a new structure on server side only the first two values are correct, and the rest are not.

In this case the struct contains 1, 2, 52428, 52428 when recieved.

Is there something I have missed during sending/receiving, or is it to do with creating the struct on the other end?

Comment: Are the client and server compiled with the same compiler using the same options? If not, aligment of the fields in the struct could be different.

Comment: Yes, both the client and server are compiled with the same compiler using the same options.

Comment: I'm not sure the correct size gets allocated for the buffer array. You should have `sizeof(header)` in the memcpy (the size of the variable, instead of the type). Print out the content of buffer before sending to make sure what you're sending is correct.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Define the wire format in octets, and write yourself a library to send and receive it. If you use structs you are introducing at least half a dozen dependencies.

Comment: Did you tried to check if the value of `bytesSent` is equal to `sizeof(Header)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, sending a raw struct over network is highly non portable :

- you can have endianness differences between sender and receiver
- you can hava alignment differences between sender and receiver

Except in special cases where you can be sure that sender and receiver share same architecture, os and compiler, **never do that**.

The normal way would be to use a portable format, either ASCII (robust but often suboptimal) or binary but you must define a non-ambiguous representation. For example as you use 4 `uint16_t` :

packing :

```
char buffer[8];
buffer[0] = header.sender >> 8; /* or (header.sender >> 8) & 0xFF if longer ...*/
buffer[1] = header.sender & 0xFF;
buffer[2] = header.number >> 8;
...
```

Unpacking :

```
header.sender = (buffer[0] << 8) | buffer[1];
header.number = (buffer[2] << 8) | buffer[3];
...
```

---

But if you had a problem of different architectures, you would not get the first two values. You current problem is much simpler : in receiving code you have :

```
char *data = new char[sizeof(Header)];
....
    memcpy(&header, data, sizeof(data));
```

And `sizeof(data)` is `sizeof(char *)`, that is 4 bytes in a 32 bits machine whereas `sizeof(Header)` is 4 * 2 = 8 bytes.

You should have instead :

```
    memcpy(&header, data, sizeof(Header));
```

---

BTW, you could avoid the `memcpy` part.

Sender part :

```
int bytesSent = sendto(sendSocket_, &header, sizeof(Header), 0, (const sockaddr*)&sendSocketAddr_, sizeof(sendSocketAddr_));
```

valid since second argument to `sendto` is a `const void *` and conversion to `void *` is automatic.

Receiver :

```
int bytesRecv = recv(listenSocket_, &header, sizeof(Header), 0);
```

since second argument to `recv` is actually a `void *`.

Comment: You can also have padding differences, or datatype size differences. All this can vary depending on hardware, operating system, compiler, compiler version, compiler flags, compiler options, surrounding #pragmas, ... Not to mention the souce code itself. The only safe way to use this technique is to ensure that both peers are built from the same object files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `#pragma pack(show)` to print the alignment as warning and ensure it is the same.

if there is a difference use `#pragma pack(n)` like this:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct Header{
  ...
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

You don't have to `memcpy` the struct to buffer. you can use your header object directly.